# Почему нельзя использовать Google maps api для отслеживания транспорта в реальном времени (как и в yandex api)?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Смотрел правила использования google maps api и там было написанно, что нельзя использовать карту для отслеживания транспорта в реальном времени (как и в yandex api). С чем связанны такие ограничения и какие есть альтернативы карт?

Comment: Уточнил название вопроса, проверьте плиз

Comment: @Kromster спасибо

Comment: OpenStreetMap смотрели?

Comment: @ИванПшеницын знаю про нее, но не нашел руководства как использовать правильно. Вообще странно, что гугл и яндекс запрещают отслеживание транспорта.

Comment: Потому что это коммерческая деятельность, с которой они хотят копеечку.

Comment: У нас в городе популярно мобильное приложение для вызова такси, с возможностью отслеживания машины, которая к тебе едет. Используют они именно openStreetMap. Я, к сожалению, лично не пользовался, поэтому ничего сказать не могу. Вот ссылка на апи: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6

Comment: @rjhdby Так а если приложение бесплатное? О деньгах речь не идет.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Сразу оговорюсь, все, что дальше - мои личные фантазии.

Вот смотрите, некая государственная служба, скажем скорая помощь, объявит тендер на разработку приложения по мониторингу местонахождения своих экипажей, что бы посылать на вызовы ближайшую машину.

Тендер выиграет контора "Рога и Копыта", причем выиграет не потому, что качественно и недорого, а по причинам вполне всем понятным.

После этого контора отдает заказ на субподряд за 10% от суммы тендера. Субподрядчик нанимает студента, который за 500$ пишет приложение и использует там API Яндекс карт.

Все живут довольные и счастливые, пока Яндекс, по какой-то причине, не отключает доступ к API, либо просто неудачно обновляет, например.

Из-за сбоя в приложении возникает путаница и к бабушке Шойгу посылают скорую с другого конца Москвы, она приезжает слишком поздно и бабушка успевает склеить ласты.

Шойгу: Кто виноват?

МинЗдравМинистр: Яндекс - это у них все сломалось!

Яндекс: А вот хрен! У нас же русским по белому написано, что нельзя использовать сервис для трекинга

UPD: Если не лукавить, то подобный функционал в 99.99% случаев - это, в том или ином виде, коммерческая деятельность. Отсюда два принципиальных момента.

1) Оно им надо, разбираться с потоком претензий от коммерсов?

2) Хотите делать деньги на нашем труде? Велком в договорной отдел, там мы вам за денюжку дадум доступ к специальному, надежному и покрытому SLA продукту.

Comment: К сожалению минус. Во-первых - домыслы, а во-вторых - Одно дело на запрет использования, а другое - отказ от ответственности. При вашем случае было бы достаточно простого отказа от ответственности. И тогда уже это была бы проблема ГосСлужбы и Рогов и Копыт, что они выбрали *безответственное* решение, а Яндекс - по прежнему на коне.

Comment: Логика ясна. Но тогда они могли написать, что не несут ответственность за использование API и небыло бы проблем.

Comment: Монетизация это отдельная тема, опять же регулируемая отдельно через запреты на коммерческое использование (полное или частичное)

Comment: @manGust А у них это написано, в конце "условий использования". Но тут опять же, скидка на людской пофигизм. Мониторинг транспорта - это такая штука, которая в случае сбоя может привести к последствиям от сильных финансовых потерь до человеческих жертв. В таком случае лучше перестраховаться и кроме таблички "высокое напряжение" повесить рядом еще одну "не влезай - убьет"